# При клике на активный элемент переходить по ссылке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет! Есть сайт http://kazdomstroy.ru/ , на его главной странице есть некая галерея работ. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы при клике на активный элемент я попадал на определенную страницу? Т.е первый раз нажимаю на раздел (он еще не активный), открывается этот раздел, при втором клике меня уже переносит на страницу. Пробовал вот такое решение, но меня перекидывает сразу.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item").click(function() {
        if($(this).css("display","block"))
        {
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
});
```

Помогите пожалуйста, всю голову уже переломал. Старый кодер не учел видимо этого и на каждый активный элемент не стал добавлять активный css-класс :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// .b-left и .items родительские контейнеры содержащие нужные ссылки
// a[class^='zom'] - выбирает ссылки с классом, начинающимся на "zom"

$(".b-left, .items").find("a[class^='zom']").click(function(e) {
    // у ссылки нет класса "active"
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        // отменяем переход по ссылке
        e.preventDefault();
        // что-то делаем...
        alert("OK");
        // добавляем ссылке класс "active"
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    // у ссылки есть класс "active" - просто переходим по ней
});
```

**update:**

```
$('.ites').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        window.location = $(this).data('target-page');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Каждому элементу с классом **ites** нужно добавить атрибут **data-target-page** с адресом целевой страницы.

Например, вот так:

```
<div class="ites" data-target-page="/news/">...</div>
```

Comment: @Lektor, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на страницу, где не работает.  
Вот здесь (http://kazdomstroy.ru/photo-gallery/) все прекрасно работает (проверял в хроме и лисе).  
В каком браузере проверяете?

Comment: @VenZell ах, извиняюсь, не пояснил. Я имел ввиду главную страницу, там где перечисляются работы. Кровельные, фасадные и т.д..

Comment: @Lektor, поясните подробнее, по клику на какой элемент должно происходить описанное вами действие? Желательно приложить поясняющий скриншот.

Comment: @VenZell вот сама панель (http://f6.s.qip.ru/131FKCUNr.png), при клике на элемент (http://f5.s.qip.ru/131FKCUNs.png) он в начале должен становится активным, что сейчас и делает (http://f6.s.qip.ru/131FKCUNt.png), а при втором клике(т.е. когда он активный) должен переходить по ссылке. ссылки в переменных будут хранится, так легче.

Comment: @VenZell помогите пожалуйста! Уже 2 день голову ломаю, не получается.

Comment: @Lektor что у вас собственно не работает ? http://jsfiddle.net/L2P9f/

Comment: @eicto пробовал аналогичный код. Не работает - специфика другая. Посмотрите, пожалуйста как устроено слайд-шоу услуг на главной странице kazdomstroy.ru

Comment: @Lektor, добавил пример для главной страницы.